# How do I find the :hover css atributes of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know I can get the color of an element by doing

```
var col = $('a').css('color');
```

However how do I get the color of that same element when it's hovered?  Would sending a *mouseover* event to the element trigger a hover state and if I then read the color would I get the hover color?

(this code is running on somebody else's page and I'm looking to get link colors to pass to an iframe so that it can match style with the parent).

Comment: Are you asking "while an element is being hovered, how can I get its color," or "how can I determine what an element's color will be, were the mouse to hover over it?"

Comment: The latter - how to discover what color it would be if hovered

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any javascript library's that attempt to predict css attributes, so yes, you would have to trigger the event and read it when triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is how do you tell what the :hover color *would be* without the users actually hovering - sending 'mouseenter' and 'mouseover' events to the element doesn't trigger the browser hover state.

Comment: Your answer would be better as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a").mouseover(function(){
    var color = $(this).css("color");
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TT8dY/)

Comment: That's only going to work if the user actually goes and hovers over the link!

Comment: In the question it is mentioned as `However how do I get the color of that same element when it's hovered?`

Comment: Question is pretty ambiguous (meaning of title doesn't exactly match meaning of content).